# AndroidAnnotations can not find Android Manifest when compile

Tags: android, gradle

I am working at Windows 7 OS, Android Studio. After compiling AndroidAnnotation framework, I can not compile project. Right during the process of compiling it responds with "Error:Could not find the AndroidManifest.xml file, using generation folder"

My gradle file is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.falcodeceo.beautifulmind"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 23
        versionName "2.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.1.2'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.1.0'
}
```

Looked through some answers but can not apply it, as I do not understand how it works. So I will be thankful if you explain how it all goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss some necessary configuration. Just add following parts to your Gradle file

```
buildscript { 
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' 
    } 
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'

dependencies { 
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.1.0" 
}

apt { 
    arguments { 
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
    }
}
```

More details can be found at androidannotations wiki https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle

Comment: it responds me with

Error:Could not find com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/neenbedankt/gradle/plugins/android-apt/1.8/android-apt-1.8.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/neenbedankt/gradle/plugins/android-apt/1.8/android-apt-1.8.jar
Required by:
    beautifulmind:app:unspecified

Comment: Then add also `repositories { mavenCentral() }` to buildscript